# Invariant measure on $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory, borel-measures

I am trying to show that the Borel measure $\frac{\mathrm{d}a\mathrm{d}b\mathrm{d}c}{|a|}$ on $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is right invariant.

Let $\left( \begin{array}{cc} r & s \\ t &u \end{array} \right)\in SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and let $f: G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be measurable.

$$\int_{SL(2,\mathbb{R})}f\left( \left( \begin{array}{cc} r & s \\ t &u \end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c &d \end{array} \right) \right) \frac{\mathrm{d}a\mathrm{d}b\mathrm{d}c}{|a|} = \int_{SL(2,\mathbb{R})}f \left( \left( \begin{array}{cc} ar+bt & as+bu \\ cr+dt & cs+du \end{array} \right)  \right) \frac{\mathrm{d}a\mathrm{d}b\mathrm{d}c}{|a|}.$$

Now I want to apply a change of variables. So set $n = ar+bt$, $m = as+bu$ and $k = cr+dt$.
Then one gets $|Jac| = |r|$ and $$\int_{SL(2,\mathbb{R})}f \left( \left( \begin{array}{cc} n & m \\ k & {*} \end{array} \right)  \right) \frac{\mathrm{d}n\mathrm{d}m\mathrm{d}k}{|r| |nu - mt|}$$ 
where $*$ is just a place holder for a longer term.
At this point I am stuck. Is the idea to just calculate right? Did I make a mistake so far? And if not, can somebody give a hint how to proceed from here?

Comment: By $(a, b, c)$, you mean the first three entries of $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Like, $\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c &d \end{array} \right)  \in SL(2, \mathbb{R})$, i.e. $ad-bc = 1$ and $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$?. A yes, the first 3 entries of $\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c &d \end{array} \right) $,

Comment: Yes, so, $d$ is a function of $a, b, c$; but what if $a=0$? This is what confuses me

Comment: I don't know, maybe it can be seen as a set of measure zero somehow.

Comment: The Jacobian is actually $r+\frac{tb}{a}$. So in the denominator you have that times $a$, which is $ar+tb=n$.

Comment: Oh yes, I see now. Thanks a lot.