# Riemannian volume vs Haar measure?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, haar-measure

Consider $SL(d,\mathbb{R})$ or $GL(d,\mathbb{R})$. Is it true that the Riemannian volume measure $\mathrm{vol}$ on these Lie groups as submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ is the same as the Haar measure $\lambda$? I feel that this is true but I am not sure how to show it.

Comment: The hyperbola $xy=1$ (and $x>0$) in $\mathbb R^2$ is a copy of the multiplicative group, and should have Haar measure essentially $dx/x$, while it seems that the induced Riemannian structure gives something like $\sqrt{x^2+{1\over x^2}}\cdot dx$? Or am I not understanding your intention?

Comment: If the Riemannian measure turns out to be the Lebesgue measure, that is, the measure $$da_1da_2\ldots da_d, $$ where the coordinates $a_j$ are the entries of the matrix $A=(a_{ij})$, then no. This measure is invariant under translations, that is, $a_{ij}\mapsto a_{ij}+b_{ij}, $ while it should be invariant under matrix multiplication.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3525551/8157) is strongly related.

Comment: @paulgarrett Thanks for the nice counterexample. I guess one can see it directly from $GL(1,\mathbb{R}) \simeq \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ with the measures $|x|^{-1} \mathrm{d}x$ and $\mathrm{d}x$.